# MySQL - creating one primary/unique key for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I've got tables like:

---

*CARS:*

> columns: "id", "description"

*TRUCKS:*

> columns: "id", "description"

---

Both tables got primary keys on field "id".

Is it possible to make sth like  one 'common', 'combined' key to both of the tables at the same time... the issue is **I need to have both "id" unique**, i.e.  when I had added *TRUCKS*: 1, 2, 3, 4..... then adding *CARS* I need to start from id 5...6,7,8,etc

Comment: Then create one table and have a column specifying the type.

Comment: It's possible but is wrong in some many aspects... would you like the correct approach?

Comment: Ofc I would :) .. I haven't said that I must use sth with primary key etc.... I've just wanted to describe the general idea

Comment: I don’t really want to have it all in one table, as its a part of sth bigger, different tables will have a lot of  different columns  and I'd preffer to have it divided and be able to easily put new tables but still have 'common' id

Answer (score 1):

```
Table vehicle
id 

Table car
id
id_vehicle
description

Table truck 
id
id_vehicle
description
```

OR (better? - depends what is Your goal)

```
Table vehicle
id 
id_vehicle_type
description

Table vehicle_type
id
name
```

vehicle_type(s): (1,car), (2,truck)

Comment: Ok... but let's say I'd preffer to have it divided into and be able to easily put new tables but still sharing >the same< "id".